# Maximum number of Spotify playlists or tracks

Tags: spotify

Is there a maximum number of playlists, or tracks within a playlist, an application, user, or the API may create?

There are several areas in the docs where the Playlist object is mentioned, but nothing that actually discusses thresholds:

[Web API > Object Model > Playlist (Full)](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/object-model/#playlist-object-full)
[Web API > Playlist Guide](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/working-with-playlists/)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the limit is 10 000 and has been there for a long time. (Worth mentioning that the limit for number of saved tracks and albums is also 10 000.) There's an [idea thread on the Spotify Community forums](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Live-Ideas/Increase-maximum-songs-allowed-in-quot-Your-Music-quot/idi-p/733759) to increase it.

Comment: One additional note, just in case it bites anyone else (I cancelled my spotify account because I can no longer favorite songs) -- an album is not a single instance towards that limit. Saving an album counts as saving each one of the songs individually. Saving / favoriting artists seems to be a separate limit, though.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no limit [anymore](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Live-Ideas/All-Platforms-Your-Library-Increase-maximum-Songs-allowed-in/idi-p/733759).